# Can one get the current gas used as a function inside of a smart contract?

Tags: gas, ether-camp, ethereum-studio

We have seen a number of instances of popular smart contracts that stored a lot of data and that "clean up" their data with a single function call. Sometimes that clean-up code uses a lot of gas and hits the maximum gas limit for a single call.

Is there a function to tell the contract writer the "remaining gas limit" during execution and then write code to exit when that level gets too low, so a clean-up could be performed with multiple calls without running out of gas?

Alternatively, is there at least a "gas used so far during this call" function?

Answer (score 3):

In Solidity, this is available as `msg.gas`, documented [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties). There's no direct way to obtain the initial gas; the best option is to store `msg.gas` to a variable as soon in the contract execution as is practical.

Answer (score 1):

on:  [live.ether.camp](https://live.ether.camp) Ethereum Studio you 
have a complete Ethereum sandbox where  you can 
imitate transaction execution and have very good 
estimation of the used gas.

More info to start is here:

http://blog.ether.camp/post/142794388568/ethereum-studio-is-ready-for-you